# How can I prove that $1+\sqrt{21}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How can I prove that $1+\sqrt{21}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}]$?

I've tried proving that  $1+\sqrt{21} = ab$ for $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}] $ $\Rightarrow  a \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}]^\times$ or $b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}]^\times$.

But can't get it done.

Comment: Hint: What norm could possible factors have?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[21]$? Not  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{21}]$?

Answer (score 6):

You can't...We have $1+\sqrt{21}=(-4+\sqrt{21})(5+\sqrt{21})$, and the two factors are not units (since their norms are $\neq \pm 1$).